# How to validate a PDF?

Tags: php, pdf

I have a PDF file, generated in php (using tFDF) that opens fine in chrome, firefox and safari. But not in Edge or Adobe acrobat reader. Edge displays a white page, and Adobe reports "An error exists on this page. Acrobat may not be able to display the page correctly".

Is it possible to retrieve what that error might be? The PDF file uses some embedded fonts that might be the problem, but im not sure.

Comment: Can you generate a sample PDF without sensitive information (replace it with Xxx's) that has the same problem? That would be very useful to make a diagnosis. I usually try passing it by tkPDF and/or Ghostscript; unfortunately, as you discovered, Adobe isn't very informative about whatever it was that it did not like.

Comment: @LSerni Thats the thing though. I wish to perform this diagnosis myself. But I dont know of a way :)

Comment: I would assume the error is in a page content stream (or in the content stream of a XObject referenced from there). To diagnose this yourself, inspect the internals of the PDF using a PDF object browser (like iText RUPS, PDFBox PDFDebugger, or many others). Detailed knowledge of the PDF specification required (or probably very much time if learning while doing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Ghostscript like this (paths are pure conjectures):

```
# On Linux
gs -o /dev/null -sDEVICE=nullpage -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE /home/ebaars/sample.pdf

# On Windows, using gswin32

gswin32 -o nul -sDEVICE=nullpage -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE C:\Users\Eric\Desktop\Sample.pdf
```

Or you can use iText (that is, `pdftk`) and ask to, say, (un)compress the file and reparse it to another file. Meanwhile, the library will performs the checks.

You can also check out [this other answer](https://superuser.com/questions/773343/validate-verify-pdf-files-integrity).

## update

This error, "'0,686 is not an operator" -- it means that it found a *number* where it expected an operator. I assume by "tFDF" you mean "tcPDF"? I suspect - I might be wrong - that we're looking at a **i18n error**, where a number such as 2/3, which should be "0.66666", is represented by the server code with a decimal comma, making it what the PDF interpreter believes a list ("0,666").

To be sure, I would either need the PDF - I would uncompress it with iText, then rewrite 0,686 etc. as 0.686 etc., then see whether this way it works or not - or the exact PHP code that generated the file, *plus* the configuration of the server (to verify whether locale settings are appropriate).

My guess is that it is a library bug. Check software versions, in case it is possible to update the code and maybe get rid of the problem that way.

I have met this bug several times, since I am from Italy and "one thousand and one cent" is written here as "1.000,01" or "1'000,01" instead of "1000.01".

Comment: Thanks. That got me some output. But im not entirely sure how to interpret it:  https://pastebin.com/a3meT4xZ. Can you assist further in this matter?

Comment: @ErikBaars are you able to provide the PDF in question? This could be really a bug in tFPDF. Do you use the latest version?

Comment: @JanSlabon Unfortunately, its an invoice with GDPR protected data and the problem only occurs when running it on production. locally it works fine!

Comment: @ErikBaars What version of tFPDF are you using? It looks like a "locale" issue. Aren't you able to create a test document without any personal data?